# Start a spring boot application inside another java application?

Tags: spring-boot, processbuilder

I have two java applications:

- a server starting with spring boot
- a client using it (through REST api)

For the time, I start both applications in differents processes.

How could I start the server from the client to obtain a "standalone" application? The use of `ProcessBuilder` to call `java.exe` is a solution, but it has drawbacks: it will be OS dependant and cannot assure the server process will be shutdown / killed as the client leaves.

Comment: Keep it simple: start the server before executing any clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in https://www.toptal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-application-programmatic-launch . Igor Delac

- opens the jar file containing the server to find the class `...loader.archive.JarFileArchive` (and some other)
- instanciates it and uses it to start the application on the jar itself.

The jar file is not extracted nor modified. Only a few classes are read.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea

Answer (score 2):

From the architecture point of view leave them separate is the best option, as you have a server and a client separate, it will be the behavior in a productive environment.

If you need it only during the development phase, and your reason to run both together is to save time, you can build both in containers using Docker. Basically create two applications, building from two different folders, and then you will start both together.

Comment: In the case of a real server, yes. But my small game will sometime run in server mode and sometime in standalone mode.